# Spring Boot Web Flux Dependency Run on Intellij and Builds but IllegalArgumentException when running the .jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-webflux

I have this issue: in my Spring-Boot application I get the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration$JettyClient]
```

when I add this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Without this dependency I can build the .jar and run it with: java -jar <JAR_NAME>.jar without problems.
When then I add the webflux dependency I can still:

1. run the code on Intellij
2. build it and creating the .jar

Then, when I run the .jar I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unresolvable class definition for class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration$JettyClient]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:332) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:160) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:420) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:325) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:129) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Do someone has this issue when using WebFlux (WebClient)?
EDIT: If I create a new project from scratch ([Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/)) with only this dependency:

- Spring Reactive Web

I get the same behavior in my machine, can someone reproduce the same error (run works/ .jar not) or it works fine for both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Client ClassNotFoundException upgrading to Jetty Server 9.4.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414074/org-eclipse-jetty-util-ssl-sslcontextfactoryclient-classnotfoundexception-upgra)

Comment: post your entire pom.xml